# gnome-power-manager is running while trying to log in. How to get rid of it?

Tags: gnome, gdm, login-screen, gnome-power-manager

After booting into the ubuntu login screen and clicking on my user name and entering the password, I get a dialog stating that `gnome-power-manager` is still running. The dialog presents 2 buttons, 1 to `Cancel` and other to `Logout Anyway`.

This issue happens about 50% of the time and I don't remember doing anything related to power management recently. Also, even if I don't choose any option in the dialog it goes away after about 30s.

This is happening on a desktop machine as well as a laptop. On the laptop I have configured power management for myself (not for gdm) whereas in desktop I have not configured power management for any user.

This is only an annoyance but still I would like to fix it, especially on my desktop where I am interested in getting it auto-login ASAP into my userid.

Any ideas why this could be happenning?

Comment: Try removing unneeded USB devices such as a webcam to see if that helps. I know this is a known issue but I forget how to fix it.

Comment: if the user `gdm` is trying to open usb devices which stops power manager from exiting, can I a) disable power-manager for gdm or b) disallow gdm from accessing usb devices ?

Comment: have you tried reinstalling gnome-power-manager?

Comment: This question was filed as a bug report.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you mark [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/563862) (note that despite the title it is not not iPhone/iPod specific) as affecting you. Currently 55 people have marked it as affecting them.

Comment: I have done that.